# Automatic deposit refunds with PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

A client wants his site to take a deposit, have a person make a purchase, then refund the deposit afterwards. I know that PayPal allows for refunds, but AFAIK this has to be manually approved by the account owner. That said, does PayPal offer a way to automatically refund a payment?

E.g. User A puts in his credit card info, makes the deposit payment, makes a purchase, and at that exact time gets refunded his original deposit.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the Refund API that PayPal provides:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APRefund

Comment: I'll look into this, but seems like just what I needed. Thanks!